# Spine.js error when trying to use its Ajax features

Tags: javascript, spine.js

I am trying out Spine.js and want to configure it to interact with my app on server side.
Here is the code:

```
var Album = Spine.Model.sub();
Album.configure("Album", "public");
Album.extend(Spine.Model.Ajax);
```

The last line causes this error:

```
uncaught exception: extend(obj) requires obj
```

What is the problem here? It's a code from the tutorial, except they use `Task` and I use `Album`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you included the ajax.js file from spine? It seems to me that Spine.Model.Ajax is not an object.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. For some reason I thought spine.js contained all the libraries in itself that were described in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

For clarity. What I had to do to resolve this issue was add `'spine/lib/ajax'` to slug.json under the modules list and `require('spine/lib/ajax')` in setup.coffee.